# Spring Batch Cron expression to meet below criteria

Tags: cron, spring-batch, cronexpression

Batch job should be triggered after every 10 minutes, from 7.30 am to 8.50pm,
Everyday in week except Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply split it into two cron expressions.

First one:
- hour 7, minutes 30,40,50, MON-SAT
second one:
- hour 8, minutes 0,10,20,30,40,50, MON-SAT

With Spring it may look like this:

```
 

    @Schedules({
      @Scheduled(cron = "30,40,50 7 * * MON-SAT")
      @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 8 * * MON-SAT")
    })
    public void doSomething() { //... }
```

The cron expressions itself may not be beautiful, for sure. However it should work as desired or at least point you into the right direction.